# ¿Se puede evitar que mi app tome el tamaño de letra del sistema operativo?

Tags: android, android-layout

Lo que pasa es que si el usuario cambia el tamaño de fuente de su dispositivo, el tamaño de la fuente de mi *app* cambia. ¿Se puede evitar esto o tengo que manejar esto yo mismo con código?

Comment: Aqui puedes encontrar un articulo bien explicado sobre el tema y como solucionarlo: https://www.digitaldot.es/como-evitar-que-cambie-tamano-textos-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes leer la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP) para mayor información.

Para mantener el mismo tamaño debes usar `dp` en lugar de `sp`.

**NOTA:** *Esta respuesta está basada en [esta pregunta de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546805/how-to-prevent-system-font-size-changing-effects-to-android-application)*

Comment: Explicación de los -1 por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Claro, debes especificar en cada textview el textSize, se recomienda usar **sp** para que la fuente se vea igual en pantallas de distintas resoluciones.

```
    <TextView
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"/>
```

En tu dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <dimen name="font_size">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```